# The built-in rpc method in go language cannot return the result correctly

Tags: go, pointers, rpc

I am completing lab 1 of the MIT 6.824 course. When I tried to use RPC to let the client call the method registered on the server, I encountered the problem that the server method could not return parameters correctly. details as follows：

## method on the server:

```
func (c *Coordinator) GetTask(args *string, reply *ReplyStruct) error {
    reply.AS = ReduceFileNames
    reply.filename = ApplyForMapTask()
    reply.MapOrReduce = "map"
    log.Println(reply)
    return nil
}

func ApplyForMapTask() string {
    if fn, ok := <-mapFileNames; ok == true {
        return fn
    } else {
        isMap = false
        sync.OnceFunc(switchStatus)
        return "map task finish"
    }
}
```

## client trying to call `GetTask` method on the server:

```
func CallWork() ReplyStruct {
    args := "test"
    replyTask := ReplyStruct{}

    ok := call("Coordinator.GetTask", &args, &replyTask)

    if ok {
        log.Println(replyTask)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("call failed!\n")
        os.Exit(666)
    }
    return replyTask
}
```

## the definition of ReplyStruct

```
type ReplyStruct struct {
    filename    string
    MapOrReduce string
    AS          chan string
}
```

## And here is the output of the console:

server:

```
2024/02/01 19:28:12 &{pg-being_ernest.txt map 0x140000ae600}
```

client:

```
2024/02/01 19:28:12 { map <nil>}
```

I want the `reply pointer` to always point to the same location, or have the same value. But the pointer is different between client and server, these two pointers point to different memory spaces, which prevents me from getting the correct results.

Comment: Can you add the `call` function and also on how you register the `Coordinator` on server side?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here, but as far as the data type goes, you can't serialize a channel (what would that even mean?), `filename` is not exported, and of course any pointer is going to point to different memory locations, because RPC is "_remote_ procedure call", the client and server don't share the same memory.